# Intuition behind the proof that pointwise limit of measurable function is measurable.

Tags: measure-theory, intuition, measurable-functions, visualization, sequence-of-function

I am self-studying measure theory.There is a very important theorem in measure theory which says that a pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable.Now,I understand the proof but do not get the exact idea behind the construction in the proof.The objective is to show $f^{-1}(a,\infty)$ is measurable for all $a\in \mathbb R$.Now in the proof they just write:
$$\{x\in X\mid f(x)>a\}=\bigcup_{m=1}^\infty\bigcup_{N=1}^\infty \bigcap_{n=N}^\infty \left\lbrace x\in X :f_n(x)>a+\frac{1}{m}\right\rbrace$$.I could easily see that the equality holds but I do not get the exact idea which led to such a strange choice.Can someone help me to understand the proof more intuitively.Can it be understood visually?

Comment: I think $\bigcup_m$ should be $\bigcap_m$ for the fraction $1/m$ plays the role of $\varepsilon$ in the definition of convergence of a sequence.

Comment: @peek-a-boo It is now clearer than before but still I haven't fully understood.Why does $\frac{1}{m}$ add up with $a$ on the RHS?

Comment: actually my bad, I think you had it right before. It should be $\bigcup_{m=1}^{\infty}$

Comment: @peek-a-boo But please explain what is going on in detail.

Comment: The idea is that $f(x)=\lim f_n(x)>a$ happens if and only if there is (i.e $\exists m\in\Bbb{N}$) a positive separation (namely $\frac{1}{m}$) between $a$ and the eventual (i.e $\exists N\in\Bbb{N}, \forall n\geq N$) terms of the sequence $(f_n(x))$ . This is quite clear pictorially. So, the point is a a strict inequality holds if and only if you can find some separation. Now, from the definition of limits, you can ensure that the eventual terms of the sequence stay well within that separation (because you're allowed to choose $\epsilon$ freely, so in particular $\epsilon=f(x)-a-\frac{1}{m}$).